# window.focus() doesn't work from setInterval()

Tags: javascript, popup, focus

I'm struggling to make the code blow work...

Then, I'm wondering why window.focus() and window.blur() methods are not working / only working from input button. They are not working when I call from setInterval().

For example, in the case below, when I push the button in HTML, it makes window at first time, and then focus the window from second time I press the button.

However, I also set setInterval() to make the window focus but it doesn't work. I can see the log on console, so setInterval function works correctly but win.focus() is ignored by somehow.

```
<head>
...
    <script>
    var win;
    function makePopup(){
        if (!win || win.closed) {
            win = window.open("","","width=200, height=200");
            win.blur();
        }else{
            win.focus();
            console.log("opened");
        }
    }
    setInterval(function(){makePopup();},4000);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="makePopup()"/>
</body>
```

So the problems are:

1. window.blur() doesn't work at all.
2. window.focus() works only when I call makePopup() from the HTML button and doesn't work from setInterval().

I'm testing in Chrome and Safari with Mac OSX.

If you could give me some suggestion, I really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, it might be a security thing, but just in case you didn't know, you can also do `setInterval(makePopup,4000);`, since it's just a function you want to call each time.

Comment: fyi, when setting that interval, you don't need to pass in a function that calls `makePopup`, you can just directly pass in the identifier `makePopup` like this: `setInterval(makePopup,4000)`

Comment: Thanks for advices! Yeah I know the way but just used to write this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser knows the difference between someone clicking a link to open a pop-up and when it is triggered by a script. In order to prevent malicious activity many browsers prevent scripted pop-ups.

By specifying a URL that is on the same domain as the hosted page, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response Diodeus! <br/> Now I call <br/> win.open("test.html","","width=200, height=200") <br/> from "localhost/". It opens the window from the script but not refocus the window once it opens then I focus another window... <br/> I would like to make the popup window active in certain periods after it opens.

Comment: Put some script into the pop-up that sets focus to itself.

Comment: mmm.. I put setInterval(function(){window.focus()},4000) in the popup html but still not working as expected. But thanks anyway Diodeus, I just started to use this site, so haven't got enough reputations for voting up but I will do as soon as I get.